# SQLite Database doesnt create columns

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create a few columns but SQLite does create always only two columns.
Im checking the columns like this:

```
    String[] str= cursor.getColumnNames();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
        Toast.makeText(this, str[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

its always only COUNTNAME and UID. (Yes i'm updating the DATABASE_VERSION)

Here is my code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="CountsDatabase";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="COUNTSTABLE";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 21;
public static final String UID = "_id";
public static final String COUNTNAME = "CountName1";
public static final String COUNTNAME2 = "CountName2";
public static final String AKTUELLERWERT = "aktuellerWert";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE ="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ("+ UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COUNTNAME +" TEXT,"+ COUNTNAME2 +" TEXT," + AKTUELLERWERT + " INTEGER" + ");";
private static final String DROP_TABLE ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME;
Context context;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context=context;
    Toast.makeText(context, "Constructor Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "onCreate Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Toast.makeText(context, CREATE_TABLE, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try{

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Upgrade Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try{
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You're iterating the columns in the cursor and not the database table. How are you creating the cursor in the first place? Also note that `Toast` isn't really too reliable logging mechanism, consider using e.g. `android.util.Log` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thx laalto, you were right. I created the cursor from an ListView that hasnt all values.

```
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    String[] str= cursor.getColumnNames();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
                Toast.makeText(this, str[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The solution was:

```
    String[] columns= {DatabaseHelper.UID, DatabaseHelper.COUNTNAME, DatabaseHelper.AKTUELLERWERT};
    Cursor cursor = sqlDatabase.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String[] str= cursor.getColumnNames();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length; i++)
        Toast.makeText(this, str[i], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```